# Issue with expected parameters in SQL statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to run a small append query in VBA to add new data for a duplicated record.

```vb
strsql = " INSERT INTO tblQuoteNumGeneration ( JobID, BaseQuote, Yearnum, RevisionNum )"
strsql = strsql & " SELECT JobID = [Forms]![JobQuote]![JobID], BaseQuote = " & _
    QuoteNumber & ", YearNum = " & MyYear & ", RevisionNum = " & NewRev & ""
strsql = strsql & " FROM tblQuoteNumGeneration"
```

However, I am getting an `Expected parameters` error. On a `debug.print`, it outputs:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblQuoteNumGeneration ( JobID, BaseQuote, Yearnum, RevisionNum )
SELECT JobID = [Forms]![JobQuote]![JobID], BaseQuote = 14937, YearNum = 20, RevisionNum = 2
FROM tblQuoteNumGeneration
```

Could someone who is a bit more versed in SQL help point me to my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect SQL statement generated. Instead of:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblQuoteNumGeneration ( JobID, BaseQuote, Yearnum, RevisionNum )
SELECT JobID = [Forms]![JobQuote]![JobID], BaseQuote = 14937, YearNum = 20, RevisionNum = 2
FROM tblQuoteNumGeneration
```

you should have:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblQuoteNumGeneration ( JobID, BaseQuote, Yearnum, RevisionNum ) 
SELECT JobID, BaseQuote, Yearnum, RevisionNum
FROM tblQuoteNumGeneration
```

Comment: That helped me figure out what I did incorrectly. Rather than doing al of them like JobID = "variable", just do the variable.

Comment: OR `INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ([Forms]![JobQuote]![JobID], 14937, 20, 2)`, depending what he wants. If a SELECT is used, then maybe the intention was to add a `WHERE JobID = [Forms]![JobQuote]![JobID]`.